# Why does it take so much time to initialize mlocate database?

Tags: xubuntu, windows-10, windows-subsystem-for-linux

While I was trying to install xubuntu-desktop on wsl2(Ubuntu 20.04) on windows 10.

It got stuck at

`Initializing mlocate database; this may take some time...`

after waiting for a long time(left it for a whole night, as I heard this process takes a lot of time as it parses through every path present on the system)

I closed the process and ran:

`sudo dpkg --configure -a`

again it's stuck at the same point.

My question is:

- How to resolve it?
- Why does it take so much time?

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Not normal. Should not take more than a few seconds on a slow HDD, a fraction of a second on an SSD. Of course, this is on Windows 10, so something specific may be going on. You may want to add in your title that this is on Windows 10.

Comment: okay, Thanks for the suggestion @vanadium

Comment: The `updatedb` command (which is what's happening here) has to traverse the entire filesystem for the name of each file. If wsl2/Windows10 has some strange idea of "the entire filesystem", `updatedb` could get confused. Read `man updatedb`, you may be able to use options to control what's scanned. Run `sudo updatedb ....` manually, once you figure it out. Once the initial creation is done  updates should be quicker.

Comment: Thanks @waltinator, I would try that.

Comment: @vanadium a 2Tb disk that is near full can take 6 days.

Comment: I have also this problem, I am using the same version of Ubuntu, WSL, and Windows that are you using

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Searching Google for this issue, I found [this gist](https://gist.github.com/mohsenkhanpour/6abd8e724e08140e1bfa253112180400) which states the following:

> [...] add `/mnt` to `PRUNEPATHS` in `/etc/updatedb.conf` in order to avoid indexing Windows files.

This is related to [this previous answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1253103/588219):

> [...] think the reason the mlocate installation took so long while stuck at 60% was because with was also indexing Windows files.

When I followed that gist instructions, it worked perfectly for me.

Comment: Agreed that this is almost certainly the issue, and a good solution.  Thanks for posting it here.  IMHO, this should be the accepted answer if the OP ever gets a chance to try it out.

Comment: This worked for me too.

Comment: In Ubuntu WSL add `/mnt` to `PRUNEPATHS` to avoid indexing windows files worked for me.

Comment: Worked for me,  on WSL 2 on Windows 11. thank you. 

I was stuck during the installation (apt install plocate), at the indexing step. I canceled out of it, and luckily the /etc/updatedb.conf file already existed. I edited that, then tried to install again. This time it completed quickly.

Answer (score 12):

I installed ubuntu lts 20 on wsl2 on Windows 10 via Microsoft Store. It didn't came with locate installed, so I installed it. While installing, it got stuck for a long time at 60% when updating its database for the first time. Thought it went into some problem and Google it (and found this thread).

Turns out it eventually finished installing after like 15 min. When I used the command for the first time, I got a surprise: it actually parsed all my hard drive into its database, including all Windows stuff, even things I can't access normally through Windows.

So I think the reason the mlocate installation took so long while stuck at 60% was because with was also indexing Windows files.

Well, if you waited a whole night, then it may be a real problem with the installation. I would suggest to install another distro on your wsl or, at least, don't install locate on it.

Comment: thanks for the answer @wsl2user. Well actually mlocate relies on a database that is reindexed daily by a cronjob. WSL doesn't handle cron. So, one could try running `sudo updatedb.mlocate`. It still takes a while to do the job but populates the db at `/var/lib/mlocate/mlocate.db`. Looking forward to wsl2 updates that might fix this.

Comment: Linux gives you a wider control on what's happening. "Don't use" is a very remote option

Answer (score 0):

So, I ran into this problem as well (stuck at 60%) while initializing mlocate database; this may take some time... However, without seeing a clear direction how to correct things, I closed all other apps and pressed "Enter" in Ubuntu (after about 10 mins or so of searching online) and low and behold it said done and I got my command prompt back and locate worked!

Answer (score 0):

How to remove mlocate:

- locate the executable
- next find out what package provides updatedb.
- nothing requires it so you can remove the package.

```
$ type updatedb updatedb
$ rpm -qf /usr/bin/updatedb 
$ apt-get remove mlocate
```

See also:
https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/113681/47662