# Ubuntu to Kubuntu How Long Should I Let plocate initialize?

Tags: kubuntu, locate

I am switching from GNOME to KDE following this [article](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/FromUbuntuToKubuntu)
and it has made it to this part of the process without issue:

```
Initializing plocate database; this may take some time...
```

That has been running for 14 hours now.  My HDD activity LED has been on the entire time, although DISK R/W reported by HTOP for `/usr/sbin/updatedb.plocate` shows `N/A`.

I have about 3 hard drives partitioned like so:

```
$ df -h | grep -v tmpfs
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda2        92G   20G   67G  23% /
/dev/nvme0n1p1   96G   18G   74G  20% /home
/dev/nvme0n1p2  820G  458G  321G  59% /working_storage
/dev/sdb1       2.3T  1.4T  820G  63% /bck
/dev/sda1       1.9G  5.3M  1.9G   1% /boot/efi
```

Should I keep letting this run?  How much longer is it going to take?

Edit: It took 16 hours!  Not sure why.

Comment: Initializing the locate database should not take that long. Is the database file present? `/var/lib/mlocate/mlocate.db` and how big it it? mine is 22 megabytes.

Comment: It is present, 5.8G:
```$ ll /var/lib/plocate/plocate.db 
-rw-r----- 1 root plocate 5.8G Dec 31 11:35 /var/lib/plocate/plocate.db```

Comment: It just finished that took about 16 hours total!

Comment: Do you have an extraordinarily high number of files? Is there something non-standard about your computer, maybe per [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1251484/why-does-it-take-so-much-time-to-initialize-mlocate-database)? It would be worth figuring out and leaving an answer for future readers reference.

Comment: /dev/sda has ~6M
/dev/sdb has ~150M
/dev/nmme0n has ~60M
Other than that, nothing non standard, no WSL, no second OS, etc.